# How to add multiple domains to my dns server?

Tags: dns, domain-server

I'm trying to figure out how can I add other domains to my DNS server, as I fallowed this tutorial:

https://tecadmin.net/configure-dns-server-on-ubuntu-linuxmint/

Can anyone explain and show me how to add more domains to my server, so I could host them with my apache server?(I know the term "host" its not the right one)

my guess its just copying those 2 lines and add other domain(and set the nameservers to ns1.example.net) in /etc/bind/example.net.zone, but is that really it?

```
myotherdomain.net.          IN        A       server's_ip
www                   IN        CNAME   myotherdomain.net.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the instructions to multi-zone are the same for single-zones, but you have to adapt your configurations for BIND9 - multiple zone files, and multiple zone definitions in the configuration.

> Disclaimer: I have MULTIPLE zones on my system with different configurations for a TON of different circumstances, and my DNS server lives on my computer with me in an LXD container.  I will be using my local only TLDs (`static.lxd`, and `chaos.local`) in my examples.

In my environment, I have multiple TLDs, but I'm going to use `static.lxd` and `chaos.local` as my two local DNS domain(s) on my network.

Firstly, I define a zone file at `/etc/bind/zones/static.lxd` which looks like this (and is the sinkhole for blocked / RPZ'd domains in my environment, as well as my Local DNS server, and my local APT repository for local-packages only, and my docker instance of course):  (most items stripped)

```
;
; BIND data file for static.local
;
$ORIGIN static.lxd.
$TTL    604800

@   IN  SOA local-dns. root.local-dns. (
             2022040201     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  local-dns.static.lxd.

local-dns   IN A    10.10.1.0
local-repo  IN A    10.10.2.0
dns-sinkhole    IN A    10.10.1.1
docker      IN A    10.10.3.0
```

I also define a zone file at `/etc/bind/zones/chaos.local` for my `chaos.local` domain:

```
;
; BIND data file for static.local
;
$ORIGIN chaos.local.
$TTL    604800

@   IN  SOA local-dns. root.local-dns. (
             2022040201     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  local-dns.static.lxd.

docker      IN A    10.10.3.0
```

I don't have any CNAMEs in my environment, but for the purposes of this example it doesn't matter.

**BOTH** of these zones are defined in `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` as follows:

```
// DNS for static.lxd
zone "static.lxd" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/static.lxd";
};

// DNS for chaos.local
zone "chaos.local" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/chaos.local";
};
```

Then you restart your BIND9 instance completely - `sudo systemctl restart bind9` - and then your DNS server will serve the proper data.

---

**You should define the base domain - the `$ORIGIN` / `@` value in my zones - as an A record, or you break things for your domains.** You need to read [explanations like this one from Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-cname-record/) about how CNAMEs to understand why I say this.

You can relatively safely add a CNAME for a subdomain to the root domain *sorta*, like `www.foo.bar. IN CNAME foo.bar.` but it can still cause some odd DNS results if you aren't careful.  But be careful, CNAMEs are VERY complicated and can cause some weirdness if you really are not careful with them.

Comment: So, the tutorial I listed in my post is only for single-zone configuration?
(sry if I missunderstand something)

Comment: @Bestmank no, you just have to follow the same steps in the tutorial to set up additional zones.  Their goal is to give you a minimum example to be functional.  You just have to go a step forward.

Comment: Can you let me understand one thing? So, if for example I would want to add another domain(account) to my apache server, through my DNS server, firstly I would create a file like this in /etc/bind/someotherdomain.com.db - https://pastebin.com/3RekNQVQ , then edit named.conf file and add: https://pastebin.com/AdLZAr8X , restart bind server, configure apache and set my new domain name NameServers to ns1-2.myhostingdomain.com ?
(hope I was clear enough with my question... if any mistakes please don't hesitate to tell me)

Comment: @Bestmank basically, yeah.  Everything you did for your first domain, just replicated for the second domain.  Adjusting nameservers, etc. accordingly if there are different nameservers per domain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And yup, myhosting.domain in example I mentioned before is indeed just copy&pasted from the tutorial. My otherdomain.com was set to ns1-2.myhosting.domain for managing it directly from my Ubuntu server(and not using registrar's dns configurations, like, for example, a hosting company who's using cPanel). Still, I hope my config file for the second domain is correct(I just removed the ns1-2 A records and pointed to ns1-2.myhosting.domain servers. Well, seems like they kinda work well. Also, again, if you spot some mistakes, I would appreciate much if you correct me!